# Finding the value of $p$ given the roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Could you tell me how could I solve the value of $p$ in this question?

> For which $p$ does $3x^2+(p+1)x+24=0$ have one root equal to twice the other root? Options given are $\{\pm17,\pm19\}$ with all possible sign combinations.

Comment: There are two possible answers

I assumed x1=y and x2=2y

Comment: and what did you get? You should post your efforts in your question body. "Here's my homework, do it for me" questions do very poorly on this site.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand,
$$3x^2+(p+1)x+24=0$$
$$x^2+\frac{p+1}3x+8=0$$
On the other hand,
$$(x-r)(x-2r)=x^2-3rx+2r^2=0$$
Comparing constant coefficients we see that $r=\pm2$, from which (comparing linear coefficients) we get $\frac{p+1}3=\pm6$. This yields $p=+17$ and $p=-19$.